# Declare vars inside javascript function and memory management

Tags: javascript, memory-management, garbage-collection

For some time I've had a doubt about js potential memory leak in this type code:

```
function foo() {

    var a = "This is my content";

    $('#myElemId').on('click', function() {

        $(this).html(a);

    });
}
```

My question is:

When foo is called, I suppose it is created an execution object, allocates memory for var a and assigns an event listener to a dom element. Once foo returns it should free the execution object but I think it won't because there is still a reference to var a from the click listener, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are right.
variables will be only freed if it is no longer needed.

In your case the variable a is still needed for the event callback so it is not deallocated. It still exists,

As another answer for this post by **elaijuh** says,It is a copy of real variable, actually it is not the copy stored in the event callback function.

You can see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3y7qbjav/ , so still you can change the value of var a after binding the click event. So the variable is ***not freed.***

```
function foo() {

    var a = "This is my content";

    $('#myElemId').on('click', function() {

        $(this).html(a);

    });
    a="new content after the event binding";
}
```

Comment: pls check my words again, im refering to `VariableEnvironment` which is ECMA-5's concept, that' absolutely not variables... `a` is changing all the way in `foo`'s execution and update the `LexicalEnvironment`. but once `foo` ends execution, `a` is deleted but another reference is pointing to the same address.

Comment: Thanks Naeem, but my question was more about what happens to execution context object, AKA activation object I believe, after foo() returns. Will it be freed from memory?

Comment: Noo.. It will not be freed as it is still needed

Answer (score 1):

it's a typical `closure` issue. actually the anonymous function will keep a copy of `foo`'s [VariableEnvironment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) but not `a`. so when `foo` ennds execution, it's execution context is destroyed as well as `a`. the anonymous function can still refer to `a` via it's scope chain.

Comment: doesn't really keep the copy of variable!

Comment: Could you call

    `a = null`

at the closing of foo?

Comment: @NaeemShaikh, you better check the idea of `VariableEnvironment` and `LexicalEnvironment` from ECMA. here is the link: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3